# Diferentes objetos do tipo Model mapeados a partir de uma única tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, modelo-relacional, orm, active-record

É possível mapear de uma só tabela do banco de dados diferentes objetos do tipo **Model** com **ActiveRecord** em um projeto Ruby on Rails?

Supondo que eu tenha no banco de dados uma tabela com o nome **clientes** que será populada por clientes do tipo físico e tipo jurídico (onde a existência do atributo CPF ou CNPJ define qual seu tipo)

[image: Tabela Clientes, a existência do atributo tipo CPF ou CNPJ define qual será minha classe Model]

e precise que as classes do tipo **Model** de minha aplicação sejam mais que uma, sendo elas **ClienteFisico** e **ClienteJuridico**, utilizando herança de uma classe do tipo **Pessoa**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o **ActiveRecord** pode fazer esse mapeamento? Caso não seja possível por ele, existem outras formas de fazer isso?

E neste mesmo contexto, quando necessito que os atributos CPF e CNPJ da classe **cliente** sejam objetos do tipo **Model** na aplicação, o que posso fazer?

Tenho esta dúvida pois gostaria de implementar as validações dos campos CPF e CPNJ em suas respectivas classes, deixando meu projeto mais coeso, mas não criar mais tabelas e relações no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

O `ActiveRecord` suporta sim esse tipo de **herança**. Para isso funcionar primeiro temos que adicionar um atributo type `para` o modelo `Pessoa`. Criação dessa tabela seria algo assim:

```
rails g model Pessoa nome cpf cnpj type
```

Ceito isso basta você criar as duas classes que herdam de Pessoa

```
# app/models/pessoa_fisica.rb
class PessoaFisica < Pessoa
end
```

e

```
# app/models/pessoa_juridica.rb
class Juridica < Pessoa
end
```

Pronto, agora todos os modelos acessam a mesma tabela. Se você utilizar a classe `Pessoa`, o `ActiveRecord` vai sempre retornar todas as linhas desta tabela, mas se usar `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica` ele somente tratará os registros com o tipo especificado. Vale tanto para inserção quando para recuperação.

A Validação então pode ser colocada em cada model separadamente, sugiro que você extraia essa validação para um `custom validator`, fora do arquivo do modelo.

#### Na párica

```
 PessoaFisica.create(cpf: '111.222.333-44')
 => #<PessoaFisica id: 1, nome: nil, cpf: "111.222.333-44", cnpj: nil, type: "PessoaFisica", created_at: "2016-07-16 17:03:29", updated_at: "2016-07-16 17:03:29"> 

 PessoaJuridica.create(cnpj: '78.425.986/0036-15')
 => #<PessoaJuridica id: 2, nome: nil, cpf: nil, cnpj: "78.425.986/0036-15", type: "PessoaJuridica", created_at: "2016-07-16 17:04:13", updated_at: "2016-07-16 17:04:13"> 

 Pessoa.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PessoaFisica id: 1, nome: nil, cpf: "111.222.333-44", cnpj: nil, type: "PessoaFisica", created_at: "2016-07-16 16:53:59", updated_at: "2016-07-16 16:53:59">, #<PessoaJuridica id: 2, nome: nil, cpf: nil, cnpj: "78.425.986/0036-15", type: "PessoaJuridica", created_at: "2016-07-16 17:04:13", updated_at: "2016-07-16 17:04:13">]> 


 PessoaFisica.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PessoaFisica id: 1, nome: nil, cpf: "111.222.333-44", cnpj: nil, type: "PessoaFisica", created_at: "2016-07-16 16:53:59", updated_at: "2016-07-16 16:53:59">]> 


 PessoaJuridica.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PessoaJuridica id: 2, nome: nil, cpf: nil, cnpj: "78.425.986/0036-15", type: "PessoaJuridica", created_at: "2016-07-16 17:04:13", updated_at: "2016-07-16 17:04:13">]>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, removeu minha dúvida sobre herança, mas e no caso em que necessito que os atributos CPF ou CNPJ sejam classes do tipo Model, mas mantendo-as como colunas da tabela **clientes** no banco de dados?

![Exemplo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3J9jm.png).

Comment: @rafakx não sei o que motivaria você a transformar CPF e CNPJ em Modelos, mas creio que na maioria dos casos não seria uma boa ideia. Qual seria o motivo?

Comment: Neste caso, para deixar meu código mais coeso quanto a métodos de validação. Faço tudo em suas respectivas classes (classe cpf valida cpf, classe cnpj valida cnpj). 

Mas pretendo aplicar em outros lugares, como em RG, aqui no Brasil existe o número e orgão emissor, numa internacionalização o documento de registro nacional não vai ser mais o RG, então prefiro relacionar por meio de composição a classe PessoaFisica com  outra chamada DocumentoNacional e nessa, ter uma classe herdada chamada RG, ID, etc (Se for EUA, será chamada ID...).

Comment: Nesse caso acho que você vai ter que usar o mesmo esquema de relacionamento de pessoa física e jurídica... Não conheço nenhum esquema de composição em Rails. Ou ainda pra ficar mais próximo de composição, use relacionamentos mesmo que você pode atribuir vários documentos a uma pessoa. Acho que não tem como fugir muito disso não.